# Are referring websites identifiable in posted html form?

Tags: html, lamp

If there is a form on one website that posts to another, will the second website know the person submitting the form came from the first?

There is no identifying information in the form and both sites use HTTPS.

```
<form action="https://otherwebsite.com/src" method="post" target="_top">
...
</form>
```

edit: If it is, what ways can it be anonymized?

Comment: Even though that info is not found in the form, it is called referer and will be sent via the header. You can read about it here. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer

Comment: Per your edit, check out this article on geek this. I think it might answer your question. https://geekthis.net/post/hide-http-referer-headers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Referrer Header](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTRQ_Headers.html#z14) is set by the browser in normal cases. So it can be used to identify the predecessor page; but not guaranteed.

Add following `<meta>` tag to your HTML page (where form exists) inside the `<head>` . This tells browser, not to send the referrer header. Tested in WAMP/Chrome

```
<meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
```

[Read more referrer policies](https://w3c.github.io/webappsec-referrer-policy/#referrer-policies)
[Browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=referrer-policy)